# Problem with deploying a MERN app on Heroku with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I am a front end developer and am trying to get into full stack. I made a simple app to understand the workings of the MERN stack. I used this (https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node) as a basis to build it. The app works well in localhost but when I deploy it to Heroku, I get a Cannot GET / error.

server/db/mongoose.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
})

const User = mongoose.model('user', {
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
});
```

server/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
require('./db/mongoose');
const User = require('./model/user');


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/getUser', async (req, res) => {
  User.find({}).then((users) => {
      res.send(users);
  }).catch((e) => {
      console.log('error: ' + e);
  })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is up on port ' + port);
});
```

server/model/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('User', {
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
});

module.exports = User;
```

package.json for server

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon server/index.js",
    "build": "cd react-ui/ && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

react-ui/Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            dataFromJson: {},
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/getUser')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson)=> {
                this.setState({
                    dataFromJson: responseJson[0],
                });
            })
            .catch(error=>console.log(error));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                Data from mongodb
                <p>name: {this.state.dataFromJson.username}</p>
                <p>pwd: {this.state.dataFromJson.password}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

react package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

[This is how the files are setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx74n.png)

I used mongodb atlas and heroku config to set the MONGODB_URI.
The heroku build succeeded without any errors.

```
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 54.6M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v4
remote:        https://mernsample1.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/mernsample1.git
 * [new branch]      main -> main
```

But there is a ‘Cannot GET /‘ error when I load the page

Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[Loading heroku app home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDqaM.png)

When I run it on my machine, this is how the app looks.
[Localhost home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ5fb.png)

I am not sure what I have missed. How do I successfully deploy it to heroku without getting 404 errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cannot GET /
```

shows that a GET request to relative url '/' is not defined in your app. As i can see you have a request defined to '/getUser' but not to '/'.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the issue. I added a GET request to '/' and the deployed app in heroku works.